# How to link AIML files to Android Studio

Tags: android, chatbot, aiml

Our team is creating a chatbot application this week. We finished coding the AIML files as well as the main codes in Android Studio. The only problem we have right now is the link between these two.

I've already placed the Ab.jar in the libs folder. Also, I've placed the AIML files in the assets folder.

[Assets folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3enp.png)

The codes I think are relevant to linking are the following (from ChatActivity.class):

```
//checking SD card availability
    boolean a = isSDCARDAvailable();
    //receiving the assets from the app directory
    AssetManager assets = getResources().getAssets();
    File seedletDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/bots/seedlet");
    boolean b = seedletDir.mkdirs();
    if (seedletDir.exists()) {
        //Reading the file
        try {
            for (String dir : assets.list("seedlet")) {
                File subdir = new File(seedletDir.getPath() + "/" + dir);
                boolean subdir_check = subdir.mkdirs();
                for (String file : assets.list("seedlet/" + dir)) {
                    File f = new File(seedletDir.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);
                    if (f.exists()) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    InputStream in = null;
                    OutputStream out = null;
                    in = assets.open("seedlet/" + dir + "/" + file);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(seedletDir.getPath() + "/" + dir + "/" + file);
                    //copy file from assets to the mobile's SD card or any secondary memory
                    copyFile(in, out);
                    in.close();
                    in = null;
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

```
//get the working directory
    MagicStrings.root_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/seedlet";
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " + MagicStrings.root_path);
    AIMLProcessor.extension = new PCAIMLProcessorExtension();
    //Assign the AIML files to bot for processing
    bot = new Bot("seedlet", MagicStrings.root_path, "chat");
    chat = new Chat(bot);
    String[] args = null;
    mainFunction(args);

}
```

---

When I ran the application and started to chat with the bot, the bot incorrectly replies "I have no answer for that"

[Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7jZI.png)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have documents, where did you start the study for building the bot? I would like to know to begin my study and implementation. Thank you! AIML + Android

Answer (score 0):

Add these two permissions to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```